# default-style when no rule applies in SLD

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld

I have this SLD associated to my `parcels`-style within GeoServer:

```
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <sld:NamedLayer>
        <sld:Name>cite:AX11001</sld:Name>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Name>parcels</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title>parcels</sld:Title>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>fsk</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>11000101902023______</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Within the settings for my layer `cite:ax11001` I selected the `parcels`-style as default-style:

[image]

However when I preview my layer in the OpenLayers view, only the feature with the fsk `11000101902023______` is rendered, althoutgh there are more features in the database. I suppose that´s because no style is associated to those features.

My question therefor is: how can I apply a style for all the features that do not satisfy the rule? Is there a way to set some default-style within the SLD that applies, if no rule is satisfied?

I´m using GeoServer 2.19.1.

Comment: You need an `else` rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a rule with a `<ElseFilter/>` that will catch all features not already processed by other rules:

```xml
<sld:Rule>
   <sld:ElseFilter />
   <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
         <sld:Fill>
           <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000080</sld:CssParameter>
         </Fill>
       </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
</sld:Rule>
```