How to define an empty default-style?
I want to skip the feature that does not match any rules.
I want GeoServer to draw nothing.
And now I can achieve my goal in the way that using opacity=0 would make a transparent drawing.  But I am worried that will affect the rendering efficiency.
<sld:Rule>
   <sld:ElseFilter />
   <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
         <sld:Fill>
           <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0</sld:CssParameter>
         </Fill>
       </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
</sld:Rule>

Any better way?

There is an opposite question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/398385/default-style-when-no-rule-applies-in-sld that suggests that what you want to achieve is rathet the default behavior. Please show your more of your SLD .

Anything that doesn't match any of your filters will not be drawn, so there is no need to create an else rule.
